# SQL Language to set a year from the current year

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I need language to set a year in an SQL query. If the current date is between 10/1 and 12/31, I need the year value to be CurrentYear-5, and if the current date is between 1/1 and 9/30, I need the year value to be CurrentYear-6. This is how I would state it, but I know this isn't quite SQL yet. [END] is the date field that is being evaluated and it contains a full date (e.g., dd/mm/yyyy).

```
WHERE
  if CurrentDay BETWEEN 10/1 AND 12/31
    Year([END]) = CurrentYear-5
  else
    Year([END]) = CurrentYear-6
 endif
```

Comment: What database management system are you using? SQL Server, PostgreSQL?

Comment: MS Access is catching the query at the moment. I hope to go to SQL Server soon, but must stick with Access for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Access with the `DATEPART()` function using two sets of criteria with `OR` rather than a `CASE` statement:

```
WHERE (DATEPART("yyyy",[END]) = DATEPART("yyyy",DATE())-5 AND DATEPART("q",DATE()) = 4)
  OR  (DATEPART("yyyy",[END]) = DATEPART("yyyy",DATE())-6 AND DATEPART("q",DATE()) <> 4)
```

This requires that either the `[END]` field is 5 years back and it's currently the 4th quarter, or that the `[END]` field is 6 years back and it's not the 4th quarter.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
WHERE
YEAR([END]) =
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(Q,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = 4
           THEN YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 5
           ELSE YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 6
    END
```

Comment: Hmm, just saw your comment that you're using Access, not sure if this will work in that, I was writing in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN getdate() < 12/31/year(getdate()) AND getdate() > 10/01/year(getdate())
        THEN year(dateadd(year, -5, getdate()))
    ELSE year(dateadd(year, -6, getdate()))
END
AS whatever
```

That should do it.

Comment: I would like not to have to update the current year every time it changes.

Comment: Ok, the current year is automated now.